# Is XMPP fast enough for MMO-like collaboration?

Tags: iphone, performance, xmpp, message-queue, collaboration

I'm looking to create an architecture for my dissertation that will combine IM features (chat messages + rosters) with collaboration (file transfer, simultaneous editing and collaborative drawing).

The clients will be a mixture of iPhone (and possibly Android) and desktop apps.

The list of technologies I've looked at is almost too long to mention, but I've narrowed it down to the MQ-like RedDwarf/Project Darkstar or XMPP with an OpenFire server.

The problem is, XMPP seems ideal for the IM functions but the overhead of XML seems to me like it might be an issue when communicating the touches on a screen involved in drawing over, say a 3G connection. Conversely, the binary messages of RedDwarf (or ZeroMQ/RabbitMQ etc) seem very fast but lack some of the higher level features of XMPP.

The question for me is, has anyone had experience using XMPP in this way (I'm aware Google Wave use(d) Google's variant of XMPP so perhaps it is), and is it efficient enough to  send hundreds of small messages from a mobile device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMPP is fast, but parsing xml does take some more cpu power than a binary format. However it is much easier to user/debug than binary protocols.

Your server is not going to be limited unless there are thousands of devices communicating at the same time, so the bottleneck will probably be your mobile device parsing and creating xml stanzas.

XMPP can also be a drain on your mobile battery life if there are lots of friends connecting/disconnecting (resulting in presence updates to be processed). That might also be something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suspect that the 3G would be a greater cause of latency than XMPP.

And use of compression greatly reduces the overhead of XML.